# Setting one's own type limits in C?

Tags: c

Can I set my own limits for data types in C? I'm solving some problem which involves some mega-great numbers, and I wish to perform many additions and multiplications and to take the final result modulo some desired number, say 1537849. So I wonder if it's possible to reset the limits of data types such that the values are automatically taken modulo the number I wish when the outcome of any of the operations exceeds my specified number, just as the processor normally does but with the limits I wish. And if such a thing isn't possible, what is the most efficient way to negotiate such a problem?

edit:

Consider one would want to calculate (2^1000) % 1537849 and place the result in the variable `monster`. Below is my attempt to conquer the problem:

```
uint64_t monster = 1;
uint32_t power = 1000;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < power; i ++ ) {
    monster *= 2;
    if (i%64==63) monster %= 1537849;
}
monster %= 1537849;
```

Is there any better way of doing so (different algorithm, using libraries, whatever ...)??

Comment: In short: no. But this is an [XY problem](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiD7Pm_97fcAhUR26QKHV0MB0IQFgg0MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AOvVaw1RW8UpIl7QYxoW-PU7zAk9): you think you want to set the limits of some existing types, what you really want is a bignum library.

Comment: You have to use or write code for big numbers. For smaller numbers, you could use bit-fields or bit-masks.

Comment: @davmac: Many people asking about taking a remainder with large numbers are working on some challenge problem, and what they really need is not big-number libraries but to think about is how elementary arithmetic works and how they can use it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil regardless, it's an XY problem. The point is, ask about your goal, not about how to achieve one potential solution that (a) might not be possible or practical and (b) might not be the easiest/best solution for the problem. By asking about a particular solution you risk missing out on good and useful information. Fortunately in this case OP elaborated so that we could recognise that this is an XY problem.

Comment: @davmac: My point is your comment exhibits an XY problem itself. It assumed a particular solution was needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it was intended more an example. If OP can give more details about the goal, we can perhaps give a better answer. Right now "bignum library" looks like a pretty good bet to me. (Although that's based on "mega-great numbers" which is admittedly contradicted by OP's follow-up example of 1537849).

Comment: @AhmedMagdy: what precisely do you mean by "mega-great numbers"? Your example modulus isn't very big. Are you asking how to do math (including the modulus operation) with "bigger" numbers than you typically can with C, or is the 1537849 value representative of what you need (in which case using `uint64_t` should be enough on typical implementations)?

Comment: Moreover, why choose C when there are languages that handle big numbers natively, like Python?

Comment: @davmac : obviously 1537849 isn't a great number, it's the number to which i want to take the modulus. say some expression theoretically evaluates to 2^1000 (a mega-great number by any standard) and i want (2^1000) modulus 1537849 (a quite modest number). i'm aware my question was ill-formatted but forgive me since i'm completely novice to this site.

Comment: @AhmedMagdy What was a bit unclear was "I'm solving some problem which involves some mega-great numbers", yet all examples _started_ with small-ish numbers like:  1537849, 2, 1000, 1, 64, 63.  For computers, these are not "big" numbers.  The _result_ of the desired function is also small-ish as when all is done, "something mod 1537849" will be in the range [0...1537848].  Numbers like `2^1000` are _derived_ from your starting numbers.  The point: to get to the result, code need not calculate  `2^1000`.  Thus the "mega-great numbers" are *not* needed if all starting numbers fit in `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I set my own limits for data types in C?

The limits of basic types are fixed per the compiler.

> I wish to perform many additions and multiplications and to take the final result modulo some desired number, say 1537849

At any stage in the addition and multiplication, code can repeatedly perform the modulo.  If the original numbers are N-bit, than at most N-bit math is needed - although it is easier to do with 2N-bit math.  Unlimited wide math is inefficient and not needed for this task.

Example code for `+`, `*` and `pow()` with modulo limitations:
[Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485)

```
uintmax_t addmodmax(uintmax_t a, uintmax_t b, uintmax_t mod);
uintmax_t mulmodmax(uintmax_t a, uintmax_t b, uintmax_t mod);
uintmax_t powmodmax(uintmax_t x, uintmax_t expo, uintmax_t mod);
```

Comment: From the question: _"I wonder if it's possible to reset the limits of data types such that the **values are automatically taken modulo** the number I wish when the outcome of any of the operations exceeds my specified number, **just as the processor normally does but with the limits I wish**"_. My interpretation is that OP is not asking for unlimited wide math, but specifically for math which is _automatically_ modulo some N.

Comment: (in other words: OP is asking for modulo after every operation, already).

Comment: @davmac As "possible to reset the limits of data types such that the values are automatically taken modulo the number" for an arbitrary number is not possible to apply a type and OP asked for "if such a thing isn't possible, what is the most efficient way", OP is allowing for alternate approaches  and is not barring unlimited wide math.  This answer asserts only N-bit math is needed.

Comment: I suppose it is unclear whether OP is asking for math that exceeds magnitude of the available integer types - I had assumed they were, but maybe they are not. I have commented on the question to ask for clarification.

Comment: @AhmedMagdy you should consider marking this answer as *accepted* if you feel it is the best useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I set my own limits for data types in C?

No, short of writing your own compiler and libraries.

> I'm solving some problem which involves some mega-great numbers which easily exceed the types' limits

There are algorithms for handling huge numbers in parts ... and there are libraries that already do the work for you, e.g. have a look at the [GNU multi precision arithmetic library (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Suggesting GMP may send OP in the wrong direction, depending on what their problem really is. We ought to learn more about the problem before recommending specific solutions, at least without mentioning alternatives, such as implementing modulo arithmetic in a way that limits the size of numbers needed.

Comment: I don't think so. From the text of the question, there are already these "mega great numbers" before even wanting to calculate in a ring. If this answer wasn't correct, it's the question's fault.

Comment: If you search Stack Overflow for “1000000007”, you will find numerous questions where the questioner is attempting some challenge problem that asks them to find some number modulo 1000000007. Quite often, the questioner thinks they must compute some horrendously large number and then take the remainder, when in fact the problems are desgined to be solvable using modest arithmetic. Thus, a naïve questioner’s assertion that they need to compute the remainder of very large number is not to be trusted without a statement of the actual problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as far as I'm concerned, if there's an answerable question, I provide an answer. After all, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: I have not disputed that you have provided an answer. I have piunted out that your answer fails to consider all that we know about these types of questions, and there is a considerable possibility that this answer will send OP down the wrong path. It is not hard to write an answer that informs a questioner about multiple options and explaining dependencies on what their problem actually is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so do it if you must.